# Remove all characters before last / in URL

Tags: php

I need to remove every characters before the last "/"

This my url :

`http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/`

And I want to have only :

```
all-about-clothing
```

Thanks

Comment: You can catch this using regex: `http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/highlights\/cat\/(.*) ` https://regex101.com/r/tG5pA6/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
$str = 'http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/';
echo basename($str);
// Outputs: all-about-clothing
```

**EDIT:**

Another Solution:

```
$str = 'http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/';
$path = pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
echo "<br/>" . $path;
```

Comment: Also check [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.pathinfo.php) with PATHINFO_BASENAME as `basename()` was meant for directory paths.

Comment: Ok, forget about that. Esentially `pathinfo()` and `basename()` do the same.

Comment: @PatrikMayer, you are right. I have updated my answer and added your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe keep the second parameter of `pathinfo()` in mind. Set to `PATHINFO_BASENAME` it returns the basename directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP's [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php) function.

edit:
`basename()` or `pathinfo()` is the easier way.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/';
$str = trim($str,'/');
$str = explode('/',$str);
echo $str = end($str);
```

// get result

**all-about-clothing**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/";
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$basename = pathinfo($url_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
echo $basename;
?>
```

Comment: That's not right. [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.pathinfo.php) wants the URL as first parameter, not the array given by parse_url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tG5pA6/1) too:

```
$match = [];
$subject = 'http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/';
$pattern = '/http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/highlights\/cat\/(.*)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);
print_r($match);
```

You can see the result [here](http://ideone.com/ZxQ2nQ).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/';
$basename =  split('/',$url);    
echo $basename[5];
?>
```

Comment: This code works with a specific url and fails if url has a different number of segments.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the above solution focus on the exact example URL,
Please be careful as if extra params are added to the end of the string,
you may get the wrong result:

http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/?page=1
http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/item/1

to cache the 3rd "directory" after the domain name, and ignore the rest of the URL, the following code can be used:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/item/1";

$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); #  /highlights/cat/all-about-clothing/item/1

$dirs = explode('/', $url_path); # Array([0] =>"", [1]=>"highlights", [2]=>"cat", [3]=>"all-about-clothing", [4]=>"item", [5]=>"1") 

echo $dirs[3]; # all-about-clothing
```